# Using php for http requests

Tags: php, http, httprequest

I am very new to PHP, and need to use an HTTP Request to download a URL that is external to my server. That URL is a PHP function that returns JSON code which I have decode. Any suggestions?

I have tried basic code:

```
    <?php   
    //Code for forming the url (which I'm sure is correct)
    $url = ...
    $response = fopen($url,"x+");
    $response = json_decode($response);
    echo $response;
    ?>
    //javascript in a seperate file that calls the php code
    var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
alert(response);
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post some code and be clear on what you need? There is nothing in your question with which we can give you suggestions...

Comment: Dose the external uri write the json in the body

Comment: Note, `fopen` and `file_get_contents` and other functions that are meant to work with *files* and *streams*, will only work if `allow_url_fopen` is enabled in your PHP config.

Comment: @Sam: Yes, it's on by default.  But it's often disabled by paranoid admins for security reasons.  (If a script is too naive and blindly uses user input to build paths, it can be rather easily tricked into executing arbitrary remote content.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$url = 'YOUR_URL_HERE';

$data = file_get_contents( $url ); // it is a JSON response as per your statement.

$data= json_decode($data);
print_r($data); // now, it's a normal array.
?>
```

Comment: Remember "//" when commenting ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `fopen` if config allows, or cURL or `fsockopen` functions to do that

Comment: I tried fopen but it didn't work. My php code is called via ajax. It builds the URL (which I have checked multiple times for correctness) and then calls fopen with the url as the first parameter and w+ as the second (I just figured I needed read/write capabilities). I then use echo to pass the response back to my ajax function where I print out the result using xmlhttp.responseText and an alert.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
$json_str = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($json_str, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use file_get_contents? E.g.

```
<?php

$url = "YOUR_URL";
$json = file_get_contents($url);

// handle the data
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

    var_dump($data); // example
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a lot of requests you can try using a http class like Buzz which will Help clean up your code https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz